# Xpath attribute and text

Tags: xpath, localization, attributes

I am learning for an exam and i can't quite figure out what i am doing wrong here.

i got this xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns=""
    xmlns:xsi="link-2"
    xsi:schemeLocation="link-3">

    <wm-stats>
        <wm jahr="2014">
            <teilnehmer platz="1">Deutschland</teilnehmer>
            <teilnehmer platz="2">Argentinien</teilnehmer>
            <teilnehmer platz="3">Niederlande</teilnehmer>
        </wm>

        <wm jahr="2010">
            <teilnehmer platz="1">Spanien</teilnehmer>
            <teilnehmer platz="2">Holland</teilnehmer>
            <teilnehmer platz="3">Deutschland</teilnehmer>
        </wm>

        <wm jahr="2006">
            <teilnehmer platz="1">Italien</teilnehmer>
            <teilnehmer platz="2">Frankreich</teilnehmer>
            <teilnehmer platz="3">Deutschland</teilnehmer>
        </wm>

        <record name="Rekordtorschütze">
            <person> Miroslav Klose </person> hat in Brasilien ...
        </record>

        <record name="Rekordweltmeisterschaften">
            <ort> Brasilien </ort> ist mit 5 Weltmeistersiegen ...
        </record>
    </wm-stats>
</schema>
```

i now need to find all the years where holland was taking part in the championship, i know that i have to look for something like this                    //wm[@jahr]/teilnehmer[text()="Holland"] 
But how do i get the value of jahr now? the correct node to be located would be jahr 2010.

Comment: Hint:you're looking for `wm[...]/@jahr`

Answer (score 1):

The other way around

```
//wm[teilnehmer = "Holland"]/@jahr
```

but your approach is not unsalvageable, either

```
//wm[@jahr]/teilnehmer[. ="Holland"]/../@jahr
```

<sup>* note that `[@jahr]` is actually superfluous in this expression</sup>

You can always navigate upwards (and sideways) in XPath.

Have a look at this comprehensive image explaining the various XPath axes available for navigation: https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts/